# I wrote some killer Javascript. How can I make it easily reusable?

Tags: javascript

I have been playing around with Chromes filestorage API. I have built a couple of functions that together automatically downloads a json-object and stores it as a string. If the last server-request was done within 24 hours. I automatically use the last version of the file. I use this for managing a huge data-dump that I do statistical analysis on.

The entire system only has one function that needs to be exposed. It's `getData`.

Currently all these functions are global variables. How should I make this contained in an orderly way.

```
//This file will cache serverdata every day.
var onInitFs,
errorHandler,
fileSystemInit,
saveFile,
readFile,
fileSystem,
getData;


//request rights to save files to system.
fileSystemInit = function(){
    //Browser specific
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

    navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1048*1048*256, function(grantedBytes) {
        //once approved (or if previously approved):
        window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler);
    }, function(e) {
    console.log('Error', e);
    });
};

//make filesystem global.
onInitFs = function(fs) {
    fileSystem = fs;
};
fileSystemInit();

saveFile = function(url, content, callback){
    var filename = makeFilename(url)
    if(!fileSystem){
        console.log('no filesystem registered')
        return;
    }
    fileSystem.root.getFile(filename, {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {

        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(content)], {type: 'application/json'});
            fileWriter.write(blob);

            fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
                console.debug('Write completed.', e);
                if(callback){
                    callback();
                }
            };

            fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
                console.log('Write failed: ', e);
            };
        }, errorHandler);

    }, errorHandler);
};

readFile = function(url, callback){
    var filename = makeFilename(url)
    if(!fileSystem){
        console.log('no filesystem registered');
        return;
    }

    fileSystem.root.getFile(filename, {}, function(fileEntry){

        //this object reads files.
        var reader = new FileReader();
        //register callback for read files
        reader.onloadend =  function(e){
            var callbackValue = JSON.parse(this.result)
            callback(callbackValue);
        };
        //read file-function
        fileEntry.file(function(file){
            reader.readAsText(file);
        },errorHandler);

    },errorHandler);
};

makeFilename = function(url){
    return  url.replace(/\W/g, '') +'.json'
}

errorHandler = function(e) {
  console.log('Error: ', e);
};

getData = function(url, callbackNewData, callbackOldData){
    var lastDownloaded = localStorage.getItem(url+'lastDownloaded'),
    oneDay = 1000*60*60*24;
    //update data if the data is old.
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        if(!lastDownloaded || new Date()-new Date(lastDownloaded) > oneDay ){
            console.debug('downloading '+url);
            d3.json(url, function(data){
                localStorage.setItem(url+'lastDownloaded',new Date());
                console.debug('saving '+url);
                saveFile(url, data, function(){
                    callbackNewData(url);
                });
            });
        }else{
            callbackOldData(url);
        }

    }, 200);
};
```

Comment: This might help you: http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/sharing-javascript-libraries-node-browser/

Comment: (-1) because it doesn't deserve the upvote that it already has. You are asking for opinions for rewriting your code, though you are not even clear about what you are looking for.. just "make it better" which means nothing

Comment: Also I think http://codereview.stackexchange.com is better for this.

Comment: He is just asking for some tips for code structuring, not to rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: Upvoted because the minus one was not warranted

Comment: @musefan, I'm looking for a way to conatin the global variables. I don't ask for making it better and I don't want a rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the whole thing in an anonymous function and expose getData only. This is the easiest way to do.

```
var getDataFromUrl = function () {
  //This file will cache serverdata every day.
  var onInitFs,
  errorHandler,
  fileSystemInit,
  saveFile,
  readFile,
  fileSystem,
  getData;

  // Your original code here ...

  return getData; // This exposes the getData function.
})();
```

In this way you only exposes one global function `getDataFromUrl`, which is exactly the public API.

For more modern usage, you may want to check out [Common JS Modules](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) and [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), which let you do `exports` and `require` both in browser and NodeJS. There is also a [UMD Pattern](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) for exporting libraries.

Comment: Alternatively just declare getData as global without a `var`.

Comment: How does this compare to making a module like this one. http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript

Comment: @Himmators This answer is like _The Module Pattern_ in the book, using IIFE for wrapping and privacy. CommonJS modules in the book are also mentioned in the answer above. The other chapters in the book include Object literals, AMD and Harmony modules, which is not the topic here. A prolonged comparison of all these patterns does not fit in the answer. They should be discussed in the book on other places of the web.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(window){
'use strict'
var onInitFs,errorHandler,fileSystemInit,saveFile,readFile,fileSystem,getData;

fileSystemInit = function(){
    // your code
};
//make filesystem global.
onInitFs = function(fs) {
    //your code
};
fileSystemInit();

saveFile = function(url, content, callback){
   //your code
};

readFile = function(url, callback){
    //your code
};

makeFilename = function(url){
    //your code
}

errorHandler = function(e) {
  //your code
};

getData = function(url, callbackNewData, callbackOldData){
    //your code
};

window.HimmatorsFileStorageAPI = getData; //  you can change the name here

})(window);
```

And you can use it simply by including this script in your page and then calling

`HimmatorsFileStorageAPI(url, callbackNewData, callbackOldData);`

Answer (score 0):

The `Module` pattern would be a good start: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript

Pseudo-class also would be great:

```
var StorageInterface = function(arg1, arg2){
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.arg2 = arg2;
}

StorageInterface.prototype.method = function(arg3, arg4){
    return arg3 + arg4 + this.arg1 + this.arg2;
}

var si = new StorageInterface(100, 500);
si.method(3, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just prototype the heck out of it :-) And use some scoped instances(using `var that = this`) to pass elements back to the parent objects from different scopes.

Now you can just start a `new FileSystemInstance()` to do your magic.

If you wish to make the more "arcane" methods private you could consider moving them to a object within your object and such, but in the end anyone with true perserverance will be able to access them. So I advice to go with a public way, and name the private methods `_fileSystemInit`, so people who read the code know it's an internalised method.

```js
//This file will cache serverdata every day.

function FileSystemInstance() {
    this.fileSystem = null;
    this.requestFileSystem = null;
    
    this.fileSystemInit();
    
    
}
//request rights to save files to system.
FileSystemInstance.prototype.fileSystemInit = function(){
    //Browser specific
    this.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    this.requestFileSystem = this.requestFileSystem.bind(window);
    console.log(this.requestFileSystem);
 var that = this;
    console.log(that.requestFileSystem);
    navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1048*1048*256, function(grantedBytes) {
        //once approved (or if previously approved):
        console.log(that.requestFileSystem);
        that.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, function(fs){that.onInitFs(fs)}, function(e){that.errorHandler(e)});
    }, function(e) {
    console.log('Error', e);
    });
};

//make filesystem global.
FileSystemInstance.prototype.onInitFs = function(fs) {
    this.fileSystem = fs;
};


FileSystemInstance.prototype.saveFile = function(url, content, callback){
    var filename = this.makeFilename(url)
    if(!fileSystem){
        console.log('no filesystem registered')
        return;
    }
    this.fileSystem.root.getFile(filename, {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {

        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(content)], {type: 'application/json'});
            fileWriter.write(blob);

            fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
                console.debug('Write completed.', e);
                if(callback){
                    callback();
                }
            };

            fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
                console.log('Write failed: ', e);
            };
        }, errorHandler);

    }, errorHandler);
};

FileSystemInstance.prototype.readFile = function(url, callback){
    var filename = this.makeFilename(url)
    if(!this.fileSystem){
        throw new Error('no filesystem registered');
    }

    this.fileSystem.root.getFile(filename, {}, function(fileEntry){

        //this object reads files.
        var reader = new FileReader();
        //register callback for read files
        reader.onloadend =  function(e){
            var callbackValue = JSON.parse(this.result)
            callback(callbackValue);
        };
        //read file-function
        fileEntry.file(function(file){
            reader.readAsText(file);
        },errorHandler);

    },errorHandler);
};

FileSystemInstance.prototype.makeFilename = function(url){
    return  url.replace(/\W/g, '') +'.json'
}

FileSystemInstance.prototype.errorHandler = function(e) {
  console.error('Error: ', e);
};

FileSystemInstance.prototype.getData = function(url, callbackNewData, callbackOldData){
    var that = this;
    var lastDownloaded = localStorage.getItem(url+'lastDownloaded'),
    oneDay = 1000*60*60*24;
    //update data if the data is old.
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        if(!lastDownloaded || new Date()-new Date(lastDownloaded) > oneDay ){
            console.debug('downloading '+url);
            d3.json(url, function(data){
                localStorage.setItem(url+'lastDownloaded',new Date());
                console.debug('saving '+url);
                that.saveFile(url, data, function(){
                    callbackNewData(url);
                });
            });
        }else{
            callbackOldData(url);
        }

    }, 200);
};
FileSystem = new FileSystemInstance();
var data = FileSystem.getData();
console.log("Data is: ",data);
```